# How to generate a Shared access signature for a folder in Azure blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I am working on generating a Shared access signature on Azure blob storage using Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET. 
Until now, I figured out how to generate token SAS on a Container and a File but, I can't find on Microsoft Documentation how to generate SAS on a specific virtual folder in my container.

Is it doable? 
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flat-namespace blob containers don't have real folders, and don't support file or folder-level security.  If you create a storage account with a [Hierarchical namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-namespace) you gain the ability to grant file and folder-level ACLs for Azure Active Directory principals.

See [Access control in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control)